# magento vat number pdf invoice

Tags: magento, pdf

can anyone help me in placing the vat/tax number on the pdf invoice in Magento?

I tried this code but it didn't work:

```
$taxvat = $order->getData('customer_taxvat');
$page->drawText('Tax/Vat: '.$taxvat, 35, 567);
```

Comment: What happens if you add `echo $taxvat; exit();` and print an invoice?  Is there any output or just a blank screen?  Have you tried `$taxvat = $order->getData('taxvat');`?

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve this by doing;
`$order->getCustomerTaxvat()`

If this value is empty you could try this;

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($order->getData('customer_id'));
$taxVat = $customer->getData('taxvat');
```