# Magento Invoice - Not displaying VAT Number

Tags: magento

Are Magento Invoices not supposed to display the VAT number.

As far as I know in the UK all invoices displaying VAT must be accompanied by a VAT number?

Can someone please advise the easiest way to add it.

Comment: Just have a look the following link [magento vat number pdf invoice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144381/magento-vat-number-pdf-invoice)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to add the VAT number to your address block here:

System => Configuration => Sales => Invoice and Packing Slip Design

Comment: On M2 the only option there is "Display Order ID in Header"